# Java to MySQL: How to update row with a value from variable?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a table `TotalSales` on my database with columns Date(Primary) and Sales. I send query thru my Java Program.

I want to add a row if Date row not exists, and if Date row exists, the value on Sales will be updated. On update, the new value on Sales will be 'current value on Sales' + 'the value of variable totalBill'.

Lets say before execution: row under Sales = 0,
         after execution: row under Sales = Sales + totalBill;

I tried this code:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO TotalSales (Date, Sales) VALUES(date, totalBill)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Sales= VALUES(Sales)+VALUES(totalBill)";
st = con.prepareStatement(query);
st.execute();
```

But doesn't work:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'totalBill' in 'field list'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have totalBill field in TotalSales table?

Comment: none, its a variable from the program.

Comment: in here you have query totalBill for table column name. Try to modify it and make it to data binding.

Comment: BTW don't call your column `Date`. It is a reserved word, and too generic. Use `SaleDate` or similar.

Comment: So, you are sending that string `query` to the database engine for execution. When it tries to excecute it, how will it know the value of `totalBill`? Only your program knows that. You need to use a parameterised statement. As I was typing an answer MadProgrammer put one in which is what I was going to say.

Comment: @Turophile Yep! totalBill has a value from my program, just having trouble on String query. Use the parameterised statement, I got the point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take advantage of the parameterised nature of `PreparedStatement`s and bind the values you want to apply before you execute the statement, something like...

```
String query = "INSERT INTO TotalSales (Date, Sales) VALUES(?, ?)
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Sales= VALUES(Sales)+?";
st = con.prepareStatement(query);
st.setDate(1, date);
st.setLong(2, totalBill);
st.setLong(3, totalBill);
```

for example

Take a look at [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

Comment: Note that `st` needs to be a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: @Turophile Well, I assumed that `preapreStatement` was assigning to a `PreparedStatement`, which was from the OP's code, but fair point

Comment: Great! My data were all string though st.setString() and instead of Sales = VALUES(Sales) + ? , its Sales = Sales+?

Answer (score 1):

You are not appending the variable to your insert query, rather simply using a string. So change this:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO TotalSales (Date, Sales) VALUES(date, totalBill)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Sales= VALUES(Sales)+VALUES(totalBill)";
```

to

```
String query = "INSERT INTO TotalSales (Date, Sales) VALUES(" + date + "," + totalBill + ")
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Sales= VALUES(Sales)+VALUES(totalBill)";
```

**ADVICE**: But for this case, you should learn to use `PreparedStatement`